# Too many values in oracle select statment

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I get oracle **ORA-00913: too many values** error when I execute following query.

```
SELECT qst.QUE_NAME,
  (SELECT sec2.SECTION_NAME AS "sectionName",
    sec2.SECTION_ID_PK      AS "sectionId",
    sec2.SECTION_SEQUENCE   AS "sequence",
    CASE(sec2.ENABLE_SCORING)
      WHEN '1'
      THEN 'true'
      ELSE 'false'
    END AS "hasScore",
    sec2.SECTION_WEIGHTAGE,
    sec2.SEC_TOTAL_SCR_WEIGHTAGE,
    sec2.SECTION_TYPE
  FROM MS_XRQ_SECTION sec2
  WHERE sec2.section_category=2
  AND sec2.SECTION_QUESTNR_FK=qst.INTERNAL_QUESTNR_ID
  )
FROM MS_XRQ_QUESTIONNAIRE qst
WHERE qst.INTERNAL_QUESTNR_ID= 'Questionnaire-3032';
```

When I run second select statement (which is inside brackets) with hard coded value `'Questionnaire-3032'`, it returns correct result.

Also when I run following query it also returns 1 record.

```
SELECT qst.QUE_NAME FROM MS_XRQ_QUESTIONNAIRE qst WHERE qst.INTERNAL_QUESTNR_ID= 'Questionnaire-3032';
```

So these two standalone queries run fine. But when I want to merge their results into one, I get this error. I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong here! Can anyone tell me why it's happening?

I would further like to pass this query to `dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype()` function to get output similar to the following.

```
<question> 
<name> Q1</name>
<sections>
<section> s1</section>
<section> s2</section>
</sections>
<questions>
```

Comment: Your subquery (starting at line 2) returns more than one row

Comment: Correct! But how do I tweak this query to get xml output in format that I desire? If I do normal join and pass that to xml conversion function then my question name gets embedded in each of section node. Sample op is as below.

<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <QUE_NAME>Questionnaire-3030</QUE_NAME>
  <sectionName>Section 4</sectionName>
  <sectionId>SECTION-103315</sectionId>
  <sequence>3</sequence>
  <hasScore>false</hasScore>
.......
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run second select statement (which is inside brackets) with hard coded value 'Questionnaire-3032', it returns correct result.

That's because it is perfectly valid as a standalone procedure. The reason it fails in your original query is that you are embedding it in the query projection. That is a supported construct but only as a scalar cursor: you have more than one column in the subquery's projection.

You haven't posted any sample data so I have made a few guesses about what you want. However, this SQL XML solution produces a valid XML document and appears to match the skeleton in your question.

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("Questionnaire",
         XMLAGG (
           XMLELEMENT("Question",
             XMLFOREST(
               qst.QUE_NAME AS "Name",
                  (SELECT XMLAGG(
                         XMLELEMENT("Section",
                           XMLFOREST(
                              sec2.SECTION_NAME AS "sectionName",
                              sec2.SECTION_ID_PK      AS "sectionId",
                              sec2.SECTION_SEQUENCE   AS "sequence",
                              CASE(sec2.ENABLE_SCORING)
                                  WHEN '1'
                                  THEN 'true'
                                  ELSE 'false'
                              END AS "hasScore",
                              sec2.SECTION_WEIGHTAGE,
                              sec2.SEC_TOTAL_SCR_WEIGHTAGE,
                              sec2.SECTION_TYPE
                          )
                       )
                    )   
                   FROM MS_XRQ_SECTION sec2
                   WHERE sec2.section_category = 2
                   AND sec2.SECTION_QUESTNR_FK = qst.INTERNAL_QUESTNR_ID
               ) "sections"
           )
        )
      ) 
    )    
FROM MS_XRQ_QUESTIONNAIRE qst
WHERE qst.INTERNAL_QUESTNR_ID= 'Questionnaire-3032';
```

I have posted a demo on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/546bee/2) but unfortunately the GUI doesn't play nice with `oracle.xdb.XMLTypeFactory` :(

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much APC. You've saved hours of my trial and error :) Here's op of query that you've suggested.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Questionnaire>
   <Question>
      <Name>YSP_001_V2</Name>
      <sections>
         <Section>
            <sectionName>Section 3</sectionName>
            <sectionId>SECTION-103314</sectionId>
            <sequence>2</sequence>
            <hasScore>true</hasScore>
            <SECTION_TYPE>1</SECTION_TYPE>
         </Section>
      </sections>
   </Question>
</Questionnaire>

Comment: You're welcome. My XML wrangling is rather rusty, so it was good to exercise those muscles :)

Answer (score 1):

A scalar subquery can only return one column and one row.

For example, you can do this:

```
select (select 1 from dual) as c1
from   dual;
```

but you can't do this:

```
select (select 1, 2 from dual) as thiswontwork
from   dual;
```

Comment: Thanks @William! That helped me to understand the basic concept :)